# "@Html.DropDownListFor" causes trouble in a [HttpPost] ActionResult. "Null Reference Exception was unhandled by the user" error appears

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, nullreferenceexception, html.dropdownlistfor

I've used a `ViewModel` to represent two entities in my database, "Categories" & "Manufacturers", because I want them as drop down list.
I've managed to create sound and working drop down lists of them both.

Here's the ViewModel:

```
 public class New_Product_View_Model
  {
    public int SelectedManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public SelectList Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCategoryID { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
  }
```

Here's the [HttpGet] `Controller` Action:

```
public ActionResult Insert_New_Product()
   {
        var dbcontext = new LNQ2SQLDataContext();
        var CatQ = from P in dbcontext.Categories
                where P.SUB_CAT == null
                select P;

        var ManQ = from P in dbcontext.Manufacturers
                   select P;

        var VM = new New_Product_View_Model();
        VM.Categories = new SelectList(CatQ, "CAT_ID", "CAT_Name");
        VM.Manufacturers = new SelectList(ManQ, "MAN_ID", "MAN_Name");

      //Passes the 'VM' to the view
        return View(VM);
   }
```

**AND** the View I have looks like this :

```
@model MyAppName.ViewModels.New_Product_View_Model
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryID, Model.Categories, "-- Select a category --")
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedManufacturerID, Model.Manufacturers, "-- Select a manufacturer --")

    <input type="submit" value="Add New Product" />

    }
```

**Everything work absolutely fine so far**

**Now** here's the *[HttpPost]* ActionResult :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert_New_Product(New_Product_View_Model NPVM)
    {
      //A few things here
      //then
        return View();
    }
```

When I click the submit button in the page, I get this error:

[See the picture here](http://ntpc.net46.net/photos/51c5ffd6b62c.jpg)

And as far as I know, it's because the `Model` in the view is `null` when the HttpPost method runs. Because the `return` in the HttpPost action, doesn't have an instance of `New_Product_View_Model`.
It's silly because I don't want to pass any models to the view **AGAIN**!
I just want the same page to be available in case I need to add more products.

I tried to exchange the `return` with this one:

```
return View(new New_Product_View_Model());
```

But I get this error:
[See the picture here](http://ntpc.net46.net/photos/93c55aea7385.jpg)

I also tried this:

```
NPVM = new New_Product_View_Model();
return View(NPVM);
```

But just got the same error.

Does anyone have any solution ?
I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTP is stateless** and MVC is a beautyful example of a being a Statless Loving web development framework. each request is like new. So you should repopulate the Collection properties when you send the model back to the view.

Consider using the [**PRG**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (***Post-Redirect-GET***) pattern. That means , If your transaction (Save to DB) is successful, you should do a [Redirect](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/) to a `Get` action to show the new product

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert_New_Product(New_Product_View_Model model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {     

    //Save & If everything is fine, Do A Redirect (PRG pattern) to Get action
    return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct",new { id=model.ID});
  }

   //Model validation failed. Reload the stuff and send back to view     

    model.Categories = GetCategories();
    model.Manufacturers = GetManufacturers ();

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult ShowProduct(int id)
{
  var item=repo.GetItemFRomId(id);
  return View(item);
}
```

Assuming `GetCategories()` and `GetManufacturers`  method returns a SelectList of Your Categories and Manufacturers, which you can use to bind the drop downs in your view.

Comment: Awesome, Shyju :)
Thanks! I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the `Categories` and `Manufacturers` to the model.
Unlike WebForms, there is no ViewState to load the values from.

The simplest fix is to call the original (GET) action.

Comment: Oh yes! I just tried to redirect to the same GET action and it did work.
Thank you :)